# sequelize, большое количество моделей-таблиц

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Есть mysql база данных, в которой есть огромное (несколько десятков миллионов) таблиц, которые содержат исторически накапливаемые данные. Таблицы все одного формата, но имеют разные имена. Используется sequelize.

Как поступить?  Cоздание и удаление новой модели на каждую транзакцию неоправданно дорого по времени. Сохранение созданных моделей не реально с точки зрения памяти.

Comment: Не могли бы Вы чуть конкретнее описать - что имеется? Таблицы с одинаковыми именами - здорово, но как они связаны между собой? Как они связаны с Вашей задачей? И, кстати, да, задача-то в чем заключается? Вы описали лишь попытку решения.

Comment: И если не секрет, что храниться в такой базе? Несколько десятков миллионов таблиц... Этак можно всю живую природу замоделировать там)

Comment: *Как поступить?* Собрать всё в одну таблицу и вменяемо проиндексировать, например...

Comment: Таблицы с разными именами. Они никак друн с другом не связаны. У них одинаковый формат. По сути одна и таже модель. Но имя разное

Comment: По поводу собрать все в одну таблицу ~50млн таблиц * на >1000 записей в год. Получится очень большая таблица. Медленно будет работать.

Answer (score 1):

Фактически, у вас есть всего два варианта действий:

1. Отрефакторить структуру базы данных, заменив ваши миллионы таблиц одной таблицей и уже для нее создать модель.

   Если вы сталкнетесь с проблемами с производительностью (а вы обязательно с ними столкнетесь) вам надо будет проставить корректные индексы и, возможно, вынести часть неактуальных данных в отдельную таблицу "архив" со своей моделью.
2. Отказаться от использования моделей Sequelize и использовать запросы на чистом SQL. В Sequelize для этих целей есть специальный метод [`Sequelize.query`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/raw-queries.html):

   ```
   sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM database_name", {
       type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
   }).then(rows => {
       // Do something here
   });
   ```

   При желании, вы можете использовать отдельную библиотеку, абстрагирующую построение SQL запросов, например [Squel.js](https://hiddentao.com/squel/)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Таблицы все одного формата. Отличаются только именами и количеством записей в них. Сейчас пока используется Sequelize.query Мы еще не занимались измерением и сравнением производительности, просто были другие нерешенные задачи, но лично я уже сильно жалею, что связались Sequelize. Пользы от него пока не было, он только мешает. А вот переписывать кучу кода пока руки не доходят.

Comment: По поводу производительности ... пока мы занялись измерениями ... 
Может кто-то сразу скажет, что быстрее 50млн таблиц * на примерно от 400 до 1000 записей в каждой или одна таблица которая все это содержит.  
Записи не большие по размеру Упрощенно формат таблиц: некий_id, время1(ms), время2(ms), price1, price2   
Скорость важна только для upsert остальное не "реал тайм"
Вот мне вот кажется, что миллионы таблиц быстрее чем одна))